# How to prevent hex value auto-completion in the ngx-color-picker

Tags: angular

When a valid hex code is typed into the color picker input, the field adds extra characters and finishes it automatically.

"ngx-color-picker" version used 11.0.0.

```
<input 
      autocomplete="off"
      name="primaryColor" 
      style.background="#ffffff" 
      cpDisableInput="true"
      [value]="primaryColor"
      [cpAlphaChannel]="'disabled'" 
      [cpFallbackColor]="'#0d6efd'" 
      [cpOutputFormat]="'hex'"
      [cpIgnoredElements]="[ignoredButton]"
      [(colorPicker)]="primaryColor"  
      [(cpToggle)]="cpToggle"
      (colorPickerChange)="updatePrimaryColor($event)" 
      (keyup)="validateColor($event)"
      (change)="validateColor($event)"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to find out your needs -

```
    [cpCancelButton]="true"
            [cpSaveClickOutside]="false"
            [cpCancelButtonClass]="'btn btn-danger'"
            [cpOKButton]="true"
            [cpOKButtonClass]="'btn btn-theme-primary'"
            [colorPicker]="classDetails.class_color"
            [cpOutputFormat]="'hex'"
            (cpToggleChange)="ckInputColorChange();"
            [cpAlphaChannel]="'disabled'"
            (colorPickerChange)="validation.color = false; classDetails.class_color = $event"
            (cpInputChange)="classDetails.class_color = $event.value"
            [(ngModel)]="classDetails.class_color"
```